# Serialize/deserialize immutable objects that carry extra informations with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, immutability

I try to use only immutables objects in my application. I've got a REST service that will take arbitrary JSon objects as input.

I've a Java class that map theses objects, and I want to make them immutable + able to deal with extra parameters (just like using `@JsonAnySetter`).

Here is my java class:

```
public class Operation {

private final String _id;

private final String state;

private final Map<String, Object> extra;

public Operation(String _id, String state, Map<String,Object> extra) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.state = state;
    this.extra = extra;
}

// getters....
}
```

Using `@JsonAnySetter` I would have:

```
public class Operation {

private final String _id;

private final String state;

private Map<String, Object> extra = new HashMap<>();

public Operation(String _id, String state) {
    this._id = _id;
    this.state = state;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void addExtra(String key, Object value) {
    this.extra.put(key,value);
}

// getters....
}
```

But this is not immutable anymore !

This will not work because Jackson do not find any "extra" json attribute to read. I would like that everything that cannot be mapped be added to my map.

Any idea of how to do this ? (or is it just possible :)

Note: I use javac with -parameters option and the `ParameterNameModule` from jackson so that I don't need `@JsonCreator` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I respond to myself :)

It seems that it is not possible to do that using only Jackson.

Because I want immutability, I've turned myself to the '**immutables**' framework: http://immutables.github.io/

With a little configuration, it will deal with extra parameters as stated in the following report: https://github.com/immutables/immutables/issues/185.

In my situation, I've got the following code:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonSerialize(as = ImmutableOperation.class)
@JsonDeserialize(as = ImmutableOperation.class)
public abstract class Operation {    

  @JsonAnyGetter
  @Value.Parameter
  public abstract Map<String, String> extra();
}
```

Refer to the documentation of immutables for the details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize immutable entity with extra arguments you can utilize builder pattern:

```
@JsonPOJOBuilder
public class OperationBuilder {
    
    private String _id;
    
    private String _state;
    
    private Map<String, Object> extra = new HashMap<>();
    
    @JsonAnySetter
    public OperationBuilder addExtra(String key, Object value) {
        this.extra.put(key,value);
        return this;
    }
    
    // setters....
    
    public Operation build() {
        return new Operation(...arguments...)
}
```

And your original class should have this annotation on a class level:

```
@JsonDeserializer(builder = OperationBuilder.class)
```

This way all your known and unknown (extra) fields will be populated inside the builder and then Jackson will call `build()` method at the end of the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. An example is below. The key tricks are that

- you can make the `@JsonAnySetter` method private
- you can use any `Map` classes you like (choose an immutable one if you like)

It would be slightly prettier if the map could be marked as `@JsonSetter` in the creator constructor but this feature is not available yet. Discussed https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/562.

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, creatorVisibility = Visibility.ANY, setterVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
public static final class WithMap {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    private Map<String, String> map;

    @JsonCreator
    public WithMap(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public WithMap(String name, Map<String, String> map) {
        this.name = name;
        this.map = map;
    }
    
    @JsonAnySetter
    private void put(String key, String value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public String name() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, String> map() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
}
```

Here's a junit test:

```java
@Test
public void testWithMap() throws JsonProcessingException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("nickname", "fred");
    map.put("suburb", "crace");
    WithMap a = new WithMap("alf", map);
    String json = m.writeValueAsString(a);
    JsonNode tree = m.readTree(json);

    // ensure that map entries are top-level properties
    assertEquals("alf", tree.get("name").asText());
    assertEquals("fred", tree.get("nickname").asText());

    WithMap b = m.readValue(json, WithMap.class);
    assertEquals("alf", b.name);
    assertEquals("fred", b.map.get("nickname"));
    assertEquals("crace", b.map.get("suburb"));
}
```